# How can I make this for loop more efficient and faster

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop

Im trying to run this kind of loop (its simplified in this example) that generates and adds up random consumption´s for 1000 clients, which takes approximately 1h30h.

```
import numpy as np

rand_array = np.random.rand(35000)
total_consumption = np.zeros(35000)

for t in range(0,1000):
   consumption = np.zeros(35000)
   consumption[0] = 0.5
   rand_array = np.random.rand(35000)

   for i in range(1,35000):
      consumption[i] = rand_array[i] * consumption[i-1]

   total_consumption = total_consumption + consumption
```

Is there a way I can make this faster and more efficient? I tried to use list comprehension to no avail

Comment: Have you tried ```sum()```? Care with ```numpy.sum()``` as it does not always return overflow errors if your type is too small.

Comment: Creating brand new arrays every pass through can be prohibitively time consuming.  Why do you need a rand array anyway?  Can't you just generate a random number for each multiplication?  For that matter, why is there a consumption array when you only need the previous consumption value?

Comment: I edited the code so it run without an overflow or syntactic error. Please check the modifications are correct. The result is a zero-based array because it quickly converge to 0 due to the product by values between 0 and 1...

Comment: @RufusVs This a very simplified example of my code, the original uses a random distribution and complex algorithm built in excel that Im now trying to port to python. Its simplified so it easier to understand.

Comment: @unamed19 is there a reason you multiply the previous value with a random number? This seems to be your bottleneck.

Comment: @Andreas Like i said this is a simplified algorithm that represents a model I developed in excel, that to make the time series smoth uses the last value in the calculation

Comment: @jwal I just did my that was not the problem as it took about the same time to run

Comment: @JérômeRichard Ty didnst notice the error's, its normal to give some strange result because its a simplified example of my code

Comment: If your algorithm requires applying 35,000 values to 1000 customers, I can't see a shortcut. Any savings would be from finding a better algorithm, or implementing the bottleneck in a faster language that you can call from Python.

Comment: The speed issue isn't with the loop, but with what you are doing inside the loop many times.

Comment: Making loops faster requires performing them in compiled code.  Compiled numpy methods is one way.  Compiling with numba is another.  But there isn't a one-solution-fits-all, especially if your code is complex and uses  imported functions (e.g. scipy)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`np.cumprod`** to **vectorize** the computation and make it much faster. Here is the resulting code:

```py
total_consumption = np.zeros(35000)

for t in range(0,1000):
    rand_array = np.random.rand(35000)
    rand_array[0] = 0.5 # Needed for the cumprod
    consumption = np.cumprod(rand_array)
    total_consumption += consumption
```

This code takes 267 milliseconds on my machine while the original one takes 11.8 seconds. Thus, it is about **44 time faster**.

Answer (score 2):

I had a try at doing the middle part with `numba`:

```
import numba
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def speedy(consumption, rand_array):
    for i in range(35000):
        consumption[i] = rand_array[i] * consumption[i-1]
    return consumption

rand_array = np.random.rand(35000)
total_consumption = np.zeros(35000)

for t in range(0,1000):
    consumption = np.zeros(35000)
    consumption[0] = 0.5
    rand_array = np.random.rand(35000)

    consumption = speedy(consumption, rand_array)
    total_consumption = total_consumption + consumption
```

The time was 259 ms versus 9.6 seconds for your code. I guess you could do more in `numba` too if you wanted to try.

Comment: This solution seems interesting but in my real algorithm im using `consumption[i] = scipy.stats.beta.ppf(rand_array[r], 5 * d[r-1], 5 * (1 - d[r-1])`. Im new to python and numba is there a way to integrate scipy.stats.beta.ppf function in numba?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that function. If you can find the source, you could try putting it into my `numba` function... maybe. Not sure.